# Why I can't call a lambda expression without parenthesis?

Tags: python, lambda, tuples

In order to be able to add 2 to the number that the function object returns, I need to call it (Of course), but I wonder why the syntax requires me to use parenthesis for that.

Works:

```
x = 2 + (lambda: 4)()
```

Does not work:

```
x = 2 + lambda: 4()
```

It almost seems that I'm calling a tuple (Which, obviously, is absurd):

```
()()
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

I mean.. this syntax is a bit cryptic:

```
x = ((lambda: 1)(), (lambda: 2)(), (lambda: 3)())
print x[0] + x[1] + x[2]
```

Comment: Precedence of operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work because of precedence. What if you had the following:

```
def x(): return 3
lambda: x()
```

Your second line should correctly evaluate for the return value of function `x`, and then create a lambda that returns 3.

Comment: This seems to do things differently from the original code. `(lambda: 4)()` is creating a lambda function that will return 4 **and** call it. Your second line only create the lambda function without calling it.